# How to prove these rules produce a Gray code

Tags: puzzle, gray-code

There is a neat N-ary puzzle that has a solution that follows a 5-ary Gray code.
https://www.schwandtner.info/publications/Kugellager.pdf

It's not the typical reflected Gray code but still seems to go through all the numbers 00..0 to 44..4, one transition at a time.

The rules are as follows (taken from the above pdf but starting at 0 index rather than 1 index)

| Transition | Lower numbers must be | Higher numbers must be |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 -- 1 | 4 | 0 or 1 or 4 |
| 1 -- 2 | 0 | 0 or 1 or 2 |
| 2 -- 3 | 0 or 1 or 4 | any |
| 3 -- 4 | 0 or 1 or 2 | any |

I would like to prove that these rules do in fact produce a Gray code for any length n, but am having trouble since a transition depends on the lower and upper numbers. In the above paper, they confirm this is the case for n = 1,2,3,4.

One thing I've tried is to show that every number besides 00..0 and 44..4 has exactly two neighbors but that's not enough to prove they all lie on the same line (there could be a line and multiple cycles, and they'd still have the property of only 2 neighbors).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For the 2-digit version you can easily verify it by drawing a 5x5 grid of the puzzle states, and marking which edges correspond to valid moves, and you'll find that it forms a nice Hamiltonian path from 0,0 to 4,4. Unfortunately I can't picture what happens when you extend it to 3 digits. I'll see if I can draw a 5x5x5 grid graph of it to get some clues.

Comment: The 5x5x5 grid also results in a nice Hamiltonian graph, but I still don't really have any insight into how this generalises to a larger number of digits. I have no doubt that will work with any number of digits, though it's kind of amazing that it does.

Comment: Thanks for the insights! I'll try drawing those out as well. One thing I noticed is that when a digit hits 2 and all digits above it are also 2 or more, then it never goes back down below 2. Once it gets to 22..22, then it follows a regular pattern. I was trying to see if I could use that to show no cycles occur. I find this puzzle interesting because it's the first N-ary puzzle I've come across that doesn't seem to have a recursive solution. Next puzzle I'd like to look at is the Cross & Crown 2013 because I think it's similar but not quite the same.

Comment: Still need to expand this thought, so adding as a comment for now. When you break up [000, 444] into [000, 200), [200, 220), [220, 222), [222, 444], then an interesting pattern emerges. In the above example for n=3, we get 50 + 30 + 18 + 27 = 5^3.
Pattern looks like
n=0:          2   3
n =1:     10   6   9
n=2: : 50 30 18 27
To get the first n numbers in the nth row, multiple each of the first n numbers in the (n-1) row by 5. Then multiply the last 2 numbers in the (n-1) row by 3.
Intuition:when top digits are all 2, they bounce around from 2..2 to 4..4 and back while bottom #s increment

Answer (score 1):

I'll attempt to prove that |$0^n$ to $4^n$| = $5^n$
Notation:

- |A to B| means the count of strings from A to B inclusive. I'll write "A to B inclusive" as [A,B]
- $a^n$ means an n-length string of aa..a
- The '*' symbol can mean either concatenation or multiplication (sorry!) but context should be clear.

I break up the sequence into parts:

[$2^j*0*0^k$, $2^{j+1}*0^k$) = [$2^j*0*0^k$, $4^j*0*4^k$] + [$4^j*1*4^k$, $2^j*1*0^k$],

e.g. [0000, 0444], [1444, 1000], [2000, 4044],[4144, 2100],[2200, 4404],[4414, 2210],[2220, 4440],[4441, 2221],[2222, 4444]

Since each transition is reversible, |A to B| = |B to A|, so we can look at the following

[$2^j*0*0^k$ to $4^j*0*4^k$]

[$2^j*1*0^k$ to $4^j*1*4^k$]

Since 0 and 1 are allowed as higher digits in all rules, and as lower digits in transitions from 2-3 and 3-4, the above two ranges will have the same size.

$Lemma$

|$2^j*x*0^k$ to $4^j*x*4^k$| = $5*|2^j*x*0^{k-1}$ to $4^j*x*4^{k-1}|$, where x = 0 or 1, $j>=1$, $k>=1$

(basically this says that if we have something like [2221000, 4441444], we can remove the trailing 0 and trailing 4, and count 5*|222100 to 444144|)

$Proof$

Key oberservation #1

Let's say you have a string [234]* x [01234]*, where x = 0 or 1 and everything to the left of x is 2 or higher, and the right can be anything. If we look at the moves where x remains the same, we can essentially ignore x since x will never cause a rule to get excluded. We can then count the transitions of x by recursively using the counts of the (n-1) string where we ignore x.

Key oberservation #2

The other key idea is that if there is a run of repeated high order digits, such as 222..2, then the digits below the run will behave the same as if it were a single 2. This will also help us to use recursion.

Let |$2^j*x*0^{k-1}$ to $4^j*x*4^{k-1}$| = c, where x = 0 or 1.

Then

|$2^j*0*0*0^{k-1}$ to $4^j*0*0*4^{k-1}$| = c (since we can ignore the left most 0 by key #1)

|$4^j*0*1*4^{k-1}$ to $2^j*0*1*0^{k-1}$| = c (this time counting down and ignoring the left most 0 by key #1)

|$2^j*0*2*0^{k-1}$ to $4^j*0*4*4^{k-1}$| = 3c (this time we don't ignore the leftmost 0. Instead, we ignore the digit to the right of it. To move the rightmost 2 in the 2^j, we need to make c moves of the lower digits to move the ignored term from 2-3, c more moves to move it 3-4, then c more moves to get the lower digits back to a position where we can move the rightmost 2 in the 2^j term from 2 to 3. Same applies to other transitions, so we always need to make 3c moves to move that position. This reasoning uses key observation #2.

So c+c+3c = 5c, which is what we set out to prove.

The same argument applies when the digit to the right of the leading 2s is a 1 rather than a 0.

Note that if $k = 0$ or $k=-1$, the above argument can't be used, but it's easy to see that |$2^{j-1}0$ to $4^{j-1}0$| = $3^{j-1}$ and |$4^{j-1}1$ to $2^{j-1}1$| = $3^{j-1}$, and also |$2^j$ to $4^j$| = $3^j$, because it is a reflected Gray code with alphabet {2,3,4}.

We also have the special case j=0, but in that case |$x*0^{k-1}$ to $x*4^{k-1}$| = |$0^{k-1}$ to $4^k{k-1}$|, which  we assume to be $5^{k-1}$ by induction.

We now have counts of all the components and can add them together.

A recursive pattern emerges:

n = 1: $5^0 + 5^0 + 3^1 = 5 = 5^1$

n = 2: $5^1 + 5^1 + 2*3^1 + 3^2 = 25 = 5^2$

n = 3: $5^2 + 5^2 + 5*2*3^1 + 2*3^2 + 3^3 = 125 = 5^3$

n = 4: $5^3 + 5^3 + 5^2*2*3^1 + 5*2*3^2 + 2*3^3 +3^4 = 625 = 5^4$

The last two terms are for [$2^{n-1}0$, $2^{n-1}1$] and [$2^n$, $4^n$].
The other terms are 5 times the term above them as shown in the proof.

In general

$F(n) = 5*(F(n-1) - 3^{n-1}) + 2*3^{n-1} + 3^n$

$= 5*F(n-1) - 5*3^{n-1} + 2*3^{n-1} + 3^n$

$= 5*F(n-1) - 3*3^{n-1} + 3^n$

$= 5*F(n-1) = 5*5^{n-1} = 5^n$

The last step uses induction where we have base case $F(1) = 5$ and the inductive assumption $F(n-1) = 5^{n-1}$

These facts together should be sufficient to prove it's a gray code:

- |$0^n$ to $4^n$| = $5^n$
- $0^n$ has 1 neighbor and differs by 1 transition
- $4^n$ has 1 neighbor and diffres by 1 transition
- All else have exactly 2 neighbors that differ by 1 transition.

Therefore you can create a path starting at $0^n$ and ending at $4^n$ that is $5^n$ distinct numbers long where each number differs from the previous one by a 1 digit transition, which satisfies the characteristics of a Gray code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave my other answer up, but I think this explanation is clearer.

First of all, I was able to write the recursion, and posted it here:
https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jtb/151cef71fd7104bb840d1fa1f54971a0/kugellagerrecursion.ipynb

The crux of the recursion is

[$2^m0^n$ to $4^{m+n}$] = [$2^m*0*0^{n-1}$ to $4^m*0*4^{n-1}$] +

[$4^m*1*4^{n-1}$ to $2^m*1*0^{n-1}$] +

[$2^{m+1}*0^{n-1}$ to $4^{m+n}$]

The leading 0 in the first term and the leading 1 in the second term never change within those ranges, so that is why we can ignore it and look at the smaller sequence. The third term has one fewer 0s than the original range, so we have the recursion

$F(m,n) = F(m, n-1) + R(m, n-1) + F(m+1, n-1)$

where $F(m,n)$ = count of [$2^m0^n$ to $4^{m+n}$] and $R(m,n)$ = count of [$4^{m+n}$ to $2^m0^n$]

Note that $F(m,n) = R(m,n)$ because R is just counting the same sequence as F but in reverse so has the same count. The recursion becomes

> $F(m,n) = 2*F(m, n-1) + F(m+1, n-1)$

It is easy to see that $F(m, 0) = 3^m$ because then we have [$2^m$ to $4^m$], which is simply the reflected Gray code on the alphabet [2,3,4].

The pattern looks like

|  | n=0 | n=1 | n=2 | n=3 | n=4 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| m=0 | 1 | 3 | 9 | 27 | 81 | ... |
| m=1 | 5 | 15 | 45 | 135 | ... |  |
| m=2 | 25 | 75 | 225 | ... |  |  |
| m=3 | 125 | 375 | ... |  |  |  |
| m=4 | 625 | ... |  |  |  |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Based on this, we can guess that $F(m,n) = 3^m*5^n$, and use induction to prove it:

$F(m,n) = 2*F(m, n-1) + F(m+1, n-1)$

$F(m,n) = 2*3^m*5^{n-1} + 3^{m+1}*5^{n-1}$

$F(m,n) = 3^m(2*5^{n-1} + 3*5^{n-1})$

$F(m,n) = 3^m(5*5^{n-1})$

$F(m,n) = 3^m*5^n$

We are interested in the count for [$0^n$ to $4^n$], which is $F(0,n) = 5^n$.